# How to fix Android Studio emulator always rotates upside?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried all ScreenOrientation, none of them works to fix this. I use Nvidia GPU(I don't know if this matters)
[screenshot of my upside-down Nexus 5 emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWsqy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added landscape orientation while generating a Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try **left Ctrl + F12.** to rotate emulator.

also [refer](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline)

Or
Unchecking the "Use Host GPU" corrects the situation. I do not know why, but it does.